# Atualizar tabela com o maior valor de outra tabela em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Possuo uma tabela chamada **funcionarios**, com os seguintes campos e valores:

```
nome       salário
 a            10
 b            100
 c            30
 d            40
```

Possuo uma segunda tabela chamada **funcionario_mais_caro**, com os mesmos campos da anterior, porém sem nenhum registro.

```
nome       salário
 *           *
```

Preciso que a tabela **funcionario_mais_caro** seja sempre **atualizada** com os dados, da tabela **funcionários**, do indivíduo que possui o maior salário.

Por exemplo, com os dados acima a tabela **funcionario_mais_caro** ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
nome       salário
 b            100
```

Não quero que a tabela **funcionario_mais_caro** seja sempre **preenchida** com novos valores, mas sim **atualizada**, ou seja, sempre haverá somente 1 registro, que é do funcionário mais caro.

Não sei como fazer isso (sou iniciante nesse assunto). Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de começar, adicione 1 registro a tabela funcionario_mais_caro.

Voce precisa primeiro saber qual é o maior salario, para isso utilize a função max(), feito isso voce encontra o nome, e por final para atualizar apenas 1 registro adicione "limit 1".

Segue o codigo completo:

```
update funcionario_mais_caro set salario = (select max(salario) from func
ionarios), nome = (select nome from funcionarios where salario = funcionario_mais_caro.salario) limit 1;
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder. O script executa sem erros, porém não faz nenhum alteração.

Comment: ja corrigi teste ai

Comment: Novamente o script executa sem erros, porém a tabela funcionario_mais_caro não é atualizada.

Comment: voce precisa inserir um registro na tabela  funcionario_mais_caro, feito isso utiliza o script que eu coloquei, eu criei as duas tabelas aqui, inseri algumas valores ,e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @Vintorisk, poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/262799/edit) sua resposta e fazer uma breve descrição ? Pois fazendo assim, **não somente** ajudará o **AP** a entender o código, como também usuários com o mesmo problema no **futuro**, e não somente `CTRL+C` e `CTRL+V` deu pra entender ?

Comment: Obrigado @Vintorisk. Funcionou corretamente.